# What is the difference between flams and drags, and flam drag?

Tags: technique, drums, snare-drum

I know flams and drags are grace note patterns (like the acciaccatura on piano) on drum kit, but is it different to 'flam drag?' or is just a matter of wording?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Flam**

```
a grace note followed by an accent
```

[image]

**Drag**

```
two quick grace notes followed by an accent
```

[image]

The amount of space between the two notes in a drag is somewhat subjective. Depending on whether you are a drum-set player (probably diddle) or a rudimental snare player (a buzz). This explains more exactly:

To answer your question: a flam drag is a mixture of both.

[image]